# How to generate separate patch files (for many local commits) and send them with "git send-email"?

Tags: git

I'm contributing to the development of an open source project which use a git as a repository for the source code.

After do some modification on the source code and many local commits, I want to generate a patches for each commit containing my signature (email address and My name) and send by email with `git send-email` to to the open source project maintainer.

How  can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Download source code from the git repository:

```
git clone git://address.of.repository/project/ /folder/path/on/my/computer
```

2) Create your git branch in the project. this branch will continue all your local commits

```
git checkout -b <private_branch_name>
```

3) set your email address and your name for the git commit signature:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

4) Do your modifications on the source code. a new files/folders could be added in the project.

Each modification could be commited alone locally:

5) Before commit the changes. we have to add the new files/folders to the local git repository:

under the project folder of the source code

```
git add <Newfolder>
git add <Newfile>
```

6) And then commit locally a modification with:

under the project folder of the source code

```
git commit -a
```

this will open an interactif window

you can check that commit has detected the edited files and the new files under:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   bin/Makefile.am
#       modified:   configure.ac
#       new file:   src/new.c
```

under the window of `commit -a`, you have to enter comment for your modifications

and then save your commit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> ( WriteOut) and then `Enter` and your commit is become saved now

and then quit the `commit -a` window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (Exit)

Note: You need to put a blank line between comments in order to get the email subject and the email core in your patch file that you will send via eamil

7) After making all the commits for each modification, now you can generate separate patch for each commit with:

under the project folder of the source code

```
 git format-patch --cover-letter -M master -o ../outgoing/
```

this will generate a patch file for each commit undo the folder outgoing

The generated files in the outgoing folder are letters containing email subject and email core and the patch enclosed in the letter.

You can check that there is letter with subject `[PATCH 00/25]`. This letter contains a summary for other letter patches with subjects `[PATCH 01/25]` `[PATCH 02/25]` `[PATCH 03/25]` ...

Do not forget to edit the file `[PATCH 00/25]`. Set the email subject and the email core

If you want to generate the patches with `signed-off-by` just add `-s`:

```
git format-patch -s --cover-letter -M master -o ../outgoing/
```

8) and then to send the letters with the git command:

```
git send-email --to=email.address@destination.com --cc=email.address2@destination.com --cc=email.address3@destination.com outgoing/*
```

To use `git send-email` to send your patches , edit ~/.gitconfig to specify your account settings:

```
[sendemail]
        smtpencryption = tls
        smtpserver = smtp.gmail.com
        smtpuser = yourname@gmail.com
        smtpserverport = 587
```

Related links: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-send-email.html

Comment: Why do you need `git commit --amend --reset-author` in step 3? Also, in step 6, not everyone uses `nano` as `$EDITOR`.

Comment: This answer is too broad, it should focus in specifically creating the patch files and sending them, and specially in the `git format-patch` command: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html